Incorrect Placement visited node set in Graph traversal DFS
I am having trouble understanding why placing visited.append((i,j)) in the else case gives me the right output, while keeping it as shown below gives the incorrect output.
I tried to debug with a simpler example
[[0,1],
[1,1]]
But I am not able to figure out why keeping it outside the else gives wrong result.
Code:
from typing import List


class Solution:
    def islandPerimeter(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        ni, nj = len(grid), len(grid[0])
        visited = set()
        def dfs(i, j):
            nonlocal visited

            if (i,j) in visited:
                return 0
            
            visited.add((i,j))  # Placing this inside else gives me right result

            if i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= ni or j >= nj or grid[i][j] == 0:
                return 1
            
            else:
                return dfs(i-1, j) + dfs(i+1, j) + dfs(i, j-1) + dfs(i, j+1)
                # U D L R

        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[i])):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    return dfs(i, j)
                
print(Solution().islandPerimeter([[0,1], 
                                  [1,1]]))


What is the output of islandPerimeter([[0,1],[1,1]]) when visited.add((i,j)) is in the else vs outside the else?

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

@Welbog 8 is right, but keeping visited.append((i,j)) outside else gives 7

If I had to guess, it probably has to do with the fact that you're returning 1 instead of 0 depending on whether empty/out-of-bounds positions have been visited.
Taking this example:
 01
 11

You're returning 1 in the following positions:
  *
 *1*
*11*
 **

How many positions is that? Well, that depends on how you count them. If you count each one exactly once (visited is outside the else), there will be 7 positions.
If you count each one each time it's adjacent to a 1 (visited is inside the else), there will be 8:
  A
 G1B
F11C
 ED

A through F will be counted once each (for a total of 6), but G will be counted twice (once when visiting from its right, once when visiting from its bottom).
This is why it's so important to be clear about what you're counting. I imagine you're being asked to determine the perimeter of this shape, which will be 8, not 7:
   _
 _| |
|_ _|


So, if I just place that visited.append((i,j)) in the else case, i get 8 as the output. I’m just trying to understand how placing this in else is affecting it

And I've explained it. When you think you've already visited position G, you return 0. When you don't think you've visited it, you return 1. You need to count position G twice. Returning 0 for visited positions means you only count G the first time you visit it.

Right, I see.. I add (0,0) G in your example prematurely and this gets skipped when I process it when exploring (1,0). Is my understanding right now?

Yes, that's correct.
